# Fiber SFP from Mikrotik RB4011iGS+RM (SFP+) to ZyXEL GS1900-10HP (SFP)?

Tags: sfp

Suggestions how to run an SFP from my MikroTik RB4011iGS+RM (SFP+) to a ZyXEL GS1900-10HP (SFP)?

Apparently I'll need a different SFP module on each end, due to the different interfaces, while making sure the TX and RX wavelengths match. There is a single fiber installed in place, with LC connector on both ends.

Comment: For a device to be on-topic here, the manufacturer must offer optional paid support fir it. Unfortunately, neither of those products has that.

Answer (score 1):

There are different Ethernet fiber PHYs for different requirements. For short distances over multi-mode fiber there are *-S* transceivers (850 nm wavelength) and for longer distances (1+ km) over single mode there are *-L* transceivers (1300 nm).

You need the same type of transceiver at each end, e.g. 1000BASE-SX (for 1 Gbit/s) or 10GBASE-SR (for 10 Gbit/s). Before buying, check that a transceiver is compatible with your device and its supported port speeds (not all SFP+ 10G ports support 1G SFP modules).

Many device vendors try to lock you in with their "original" transceivers but there's a vast market of compatible 3rd party SFPs that work just as well.

Another option for 10 Gbit/s is a direct-attach copper cable (DAC) that has fitted SFP+ modules on each end. If you use those between devices from different vendors that are both locking in, you need to find a supplier that offers custom-programmed DACs with different compatibilities at their ends.